# How to set the Value in an Autocomplete Component MUI with React-Hook-Forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form, form-data

My Formdata has

```
`agreementHeaderData.salesPerson ={{
                  id: "2",
                  name: "Jhon,Snow",
                  label: "Jhon,Snow",
                  value: "Jhon.Snow@reliance.com",
                  filter_field: null,
                }}`
```

And I want my formData to preset my autocomplete.
Can someone please help ?

I have used this Controller to wrap my Autocomplete

```
<Controller
            name="agreementHeaderData.salesPerson"
            control={props.formControl}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <Autocomplete
                className="salesPerson"
                {...field}
                fullWidth
                disablePortal
                id="salesPerson"
                onChange={(event, item) => {
                  field.onChange(item);
                }}
                options={salesPerson}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} required label="Sales Person" variant="filled" size="small" />}
              />
            )}
          />
```

but doing this clears the data from the form data and makes
agreementHeaderData.salesPerson=""

Comment: It looks like you need to give a defaultValue to your Autocomplete component. If you have more problems with your structure, you'll need to implement your own logic in the isOptionEqualToValue property

Answer (score 0):

you should pass defaultValues to useForm

```
  const { control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      agreementHeaderData: {
        salesPerson
      },
    },
  })
```

I create a [reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/hook-form-6mjvh3?file=/src/App.tsx), it looks like everything's right.

btw, add "value" to prevent errors, add "isOptionEqualToValue" to make option selected

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(a, b) => a.id === b.id}
value={field.value || null}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks  for the reply I have passed the default values to useForm still the data is not being populated to Autocomplete any other suggestions

Comment: I want the onChange because I want the whole object not just the label in the value, If I remove that I'm not getting the required output

Comment: I am not sure what it means "makes agreementHeaderData.salesPerson=''   " , and I've created a reproduction that may help you.

Comment: If I am commenting out the Autocomplete component I get the values from getValues in form data but if I Uncomment the Autocomplete block and check the value by getValues  it logs a blank string